# MATLAB dct2/idct2 vs. dctmtx

Tags: matlab, dct

There are two alternative methods to compute DCT and its inverse in MATLAB. One is `dct2`/`idct2` and the other is the transformation matrix computed by `dctmtx`. Why is there an alternative way based on matrix multiplications making use of `dctmtx`?

Answer (score 4):

"If A is square, the two-dimensional DCT of A can be computed as D*A*D'. This computation is sometimes faster than using dct2, especially if you are computing a large number of small DCTs, because D needs to be determined only once."

Where `D = dctmtx(n)`

Source: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/dctmtx.html

Comment: The weird thing is, it is not completely true. Using matlab `dct2` and  the `D*I*D'` method gives slightly different results.